# What is the area under $9-x^2$ between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: integration, area

I want to find the area under $9-x^2$ between $0$ and $1$. I found $1/3$ but wolfram says that it isn't correct and gives me $26/3$.

I evaluated my area by using the limit of $n$ going to infinity of the sum of $k^2/n^3$ from $k=1$ to $n$.

Comment: The area given by $\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ is $1/3$, did you forget to do the $9-\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ part?

Comment: I don't understand your method to find the area. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Astroman, you asked 69 questions on this site, you should invest a little bit of your time learning how to format them. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: 69, eh? One should really learn once he hits that 69 mark...

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot the 9 part. Thank you... I guess I need sleep.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 (9-x^2)\ dx = \left(9x - \frac{x^3}3{}\right)_0^1$$

$$ = 9 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{26}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a simple $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k^2}{n^3}$,

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1(9-x^2)\ dx 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1n\cdot\left[9-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac9n-\frac{k^2}{n^3}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac9n\sum_{k=1}^{n}1-\frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac9n\cdot n-\frac1{n^3}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right]\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[9-\frac{1\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(2+\frac1n\right)}6\right]\\
&= 9-\frac13\\
&= \frac{26}3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wait, isn't my sum the correct one ? How come ?

Comment: @Astroman my guess is that you forgot to do the $9-$, and you should show how you worked that out in order for others to help.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the 9 part. I need sleep or need to do something else. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you make the calculus before to take the limit? Its fastest to write, and also if the limit does not exist and you don't know it at the begining its not really great.

Comment: @Shadock what do you mean by "make the calculus before to take the limit"?

Comment: Instead of write $\lim$ in front of the begining of your 5th first lines, I think its better to make the calculus of the sum (finite sum) and take the limit when n goes to infinity after to be sure the limit exist. :) Obviously we know here the limit exist but... well

Answer (score 0):

By "under the curve" I assume you mean bound by the curve and the x-axis. The requested area is $\int_{0}^{1} 9-x^2\, dx$. We can easily calculate this integral using the fact that $\int x^n\, dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$, and we get $9x-\frac{x^3}{3}+C$. Evaluating this from the limits $0,1$ we get $\frac{26}{3}-0=\frac{26}{3}$